# DiscretePlot: differentiate without using different colors

Tags: plotting, data, visualization

I need to plot multiple series in the same figure. As the picture will be printed in white and black only, how can I differentiate these series so that readers can identify them from each other? Thanks!

Comment: @Bill, he doesn't want colors since he'll be printing in black and white; this calls for using different *shapes* as the plot markers. Maybe different dashing and thickness styles too if the points are joined.

Answer (score 6):

```
data = Table[
   PDF[BinomialDistribution[50, p], k], {p, {0.3, 0.5, 0.8}}];

DiscretePlot[
 Evaluate@data, {k, 1, 50},
 PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Black, Opacity[.5],
    AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}]],
   Directive[Black, Opacity[.5],
    AbsoluteDashing[{10, 10}]],
   Directive[Black, Opacity[.5],
    AbsoluteDashing[{0, 0}]]},
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium},
 PlotLegends -> {0.3, 0.5, 0.8}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you BoB. One more question is, based on your code, can I plot every 10th point on the x-axis? I have 240 data points. If I plot all of them together, it is too crowded.

Comment: @David, look up `Span[]` or `Take[]` for that.

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu - also look at [Downsample](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Downsample.html)

Answer (score -1):

Sincerely David, it's not so difficult to look at the documentation

```
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Dashing[.1], Dashing[0.01]}]
```

Hope it will do the task

Comment: Sincerely Cyrille, the OP was asking about `DiscretePlot[]`, so an answer involving that function would be certainly more germane.

Comment: I realize that I have not reading the question with enough attention. Sorry